# Know When a listener's method has been called

Tags: java

I am struggling trying to google this subject. I must not being using the correct search terms. I have a location listener, in Android, and I usually nest the listener inside the class I am using it for.

```
public class ClassName {
    ...
    private class Listener implements SomeListener{
        ...
        public void somethingChanged(){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This time I decided to make the listener a new class to make the code easier to read and so I can reuse it. So now my listener and the class that is using the listener are separate.

```
public class ClassName{
    ...
}

public class Listener implements SomeListener{
    ...
    public void somethingChanged(){
        ...
    }
}
```

So inside the `somethingChanged()` method, I just want to notify my main class that an event has occurred so I can do some updating. I can't think of a way to do this. I can't put anything specific in the listener's method or it is not reusable. How do I make a method that has been called from a Listener call a method in the class using the listener?

Comment: Is that the way to go, Tudor? Or should I just always nest the listener?

Comment: The observer pattern is a general pattern when you want an entity to notify other entities of changes, without tightly coupling their implementations.

Comment: Using the observer pattern is an elegant way to solve your problem, unless of course you can't just nest the classes and be done with it.

Comment: I guess I will just nest the class every time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you see, the inner class knows the outer class, which is not the case any more since  you separated the classes.

I would suggest passing the instance of `ClassName` to a `Listener` in a constructor, and calling the `ClassName`'s public methods from within `somethingChanged`.

Comment: Then I can't reuse the listener with other classes. Or could I do what you said, but make any class that wants to use the listener implement a single method that the listener calls when an event is fired. This sounds like it might be a common thing that I am unaware of or am not connecting. I will research it.

Comment: @l3v: Then introduce an interface with the method to call when an event has occured. The your classes can implement this interface and you an pass this to the listeners.

Comment: @l3v: ... or maybe make the listener a generic class. You'll need to know which method should be called, though => interface is a better idea.

Comment: @l3v: another idea would be to use a local anonymous class derived from `Listener<ClassName>` inside `ClassName`, implementing the needed callback function as the call to the `ClassName`'s method. Too bad Java doesn't have delegates.

Comment: I agree, delegates would be nice. Thanks for the information.